# Exclude div from jquery mobile transition fx

Tags: jquery, mobile

Is it possible to exclude an element from the jquery mobile transition fx? 
For example I have a fixed toolbar and want the page to flip except for the toolbar. Is this possible? I've seen a similar effect in jqTouch.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show some codes so we can make some fiddles based on it?
You could probably use something like

```
 $('.item').not('.exclude')
```

Comment: This is the site under development: http://dev.mobileversion.co

I'd like to have the logo at the top stay in place while the rest of the page transitions.

Comment: Have you tried making some fixed toolbars? http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html